# Define list at module level or within class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class method that validates that a dictionary contains all of the keys that I expect it to by comparing the dictionary to a list.

Currently, I have the set defined at the module level of my class, like so:

```
expected_keys = {
    'key1',
    'key2',
    'key3',
    'key4',
}

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, config_dict):
        try:
            self.validate_configs(configs)
        except TypeError, ValueError:
            raise

        ...

    def validate_configs(self, config_dict):
        if not isinstance (config_dict, dict):
            raise TypeError('Config structure is not a dictionary.')

        if not expected_keys == config_dict.keys():
            raise ValueError('Config dict does not have all necessary keys.')
```

Is this the best (performance and practice-wise) way to do this? I plan on having possibly hundreds of these objects instantiated at a time, and I'm not sure if the current method will cause any performance hits. The real `expected_keys` set contains ~30 entries as well. I can get over how ugly it looks in my source file so long as I'm doing things correctly ("there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it").

Comment: Your `all` test checks that `expected_keys` is a subset of the keys of `config_dict`. You can do that faster with set operations, so  `expected_keys` should be a set, not a list. (`config_dict.keys()` is automatically a set-like object). Is it supposed to be a subset, or should the 2 sets be equal?

Comment: The two sets should be equal. I suppose maybe then that I should check for the equality between `config_dict.keys()` and `expected_keys`? I do know that `config_dict.keys()` will return a `dict_keys` object, though.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the `try` in `__init__` if all you're going to do in the `except` is `raise`. That will happen automatically.

Comment: @PM2Ring fair point- though in the actual implementation it happens in a different function elsewhere in the class. This was my quick-n'-dirty-but-still-working example. I will absolutely keep that in mind for my future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @PM2Ring's comment, you should do a few things:

1.) Change your `expected_keys` to a `set` (currently it's a `tuple`.  A set is denoted with `{}`).  Per @PM2Ring's comment you can keep it neat and tidy by having it as a `class attribute` instead if it's fixed for the class object:

```
class Spam(object):
    expected_keys = {
        'key1',
        'key2',
        'key3',
        'key4',
    }

    def __init__(self, config_dict):
        # continue defining the rest of your class...
```

2.) Change your last validation as such:

```
if not expected_keys.issubset(config_dict.keys()):
    raise ValueError('Config dict does not have all necessary keys.')
```

This checks to see if `config_dict` contains all of your `expected_keys`, but will still validate if `config_dict` has other different keys than expected.

If per your comment the `config_dict` must have the exact keys (**no more and no less**) than the `expected_keys`, then you should validate as:

```
if not expected_keys == config_dict.keys():
    raise ValueError('Config dict does not have all necessary keys.')
```

Comment: @PM2Ring this is what I was looking for (note: the help with writing the code I was trying to write to begin with is also much appreciated). So, even if I have hundreds of these objects instantiated, having `expected_keys` as a class attribute (defined before `__init__`, perhaps) would be the "best way" to do it?

Comment: @questionable_code provided your `expected_keys` remain the same across the class (i.e. it's not different between instances), having it inside the class makes the most sense as it really belongs inside the object instead of the main body.  Performance wise I don't think it would make a difference.  If you did however set it as an instance attribute (`self.expected_keys`) then it could impact performance if you instantiate an ungodly amount.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @questionable_code A class attribute is shared by all instances, it isn't copied into the instances. So it uses the same amount of RAM as making it a global. And yes, defining a class attribute before the `__init__` is the usual practice. You just use the bare name `expected_keys` for the definition, but inside the methods you can read from it with `Spam.expected_keys` or `self.expected_keys`.

Comment: @questionable_code FWIW, you might like to add more info to that ValueError message. Eg, you can do `keys = config_dict.keys()`, see if `keys` equals `self.expected_keys, and if that fails, calculate `missing = self.expected_keys - keys; unknown = keys - self.expected_keys` and print the results.

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting, I didn't believe `self.expected_keys` would be a valid reference but indeed it is.  I would have imagined it's limited to `Spam.expected_keys` only.

Comment: The name resolution on `self.expected_keys` first checks for an instance attribute, and if it doesn't find one, it looks for a class attribute.

Comment: The name resolution thing is important when you want to assign to a class attribute. So `Spam.expected_keys = {'new'}` would _replace_ the existing class attribute, but `self.expected_keys = {'new'}` would create a new instance attribute instead, and from that point on `self.expected_keys` would refer to that instance attribute.

Comment: None of that stuff is relevant for this case though, since `Spam.expected_keys` is a constant. But if we wanted to we could add to it or remove keys, using either `Spam.expected_keys` or `self.expected_keys`, since that merely mutates the existing object, it doesn't replace it like assignment does.

Comment: Going on your additional comments, I did a few experiments on the matter.  If I had a `class Foo()` with class attribute `bar` (not `Foo.bar`), once I assign a value to `self.bar`, `bar` can no longer be referenced back within the class (`NameError: name 'bar' is not defined`).  However if I explicitly reference to `Foo.bar` within the class, it can still retrieve the value.  This proves to be an interesting experiment, thanks.

Comment: @PM2Ring that's a great point. My application is a scientific share-in-lab kind of deal where my colleagues are encouraged to write their own implementations based on my base-code, so that could be an especially handy thing to do.